# Database model name change and table change Visual Studio still looks for at old table name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am having a weird issue with my project. I have 2 models in my project and they are called Job and Jobs. Originally when I started the project it created the tables in SQL as Jobs and Jobs1. I am confused as to why it called the tables these names. When I deleted the tables in SQL and recreated them to add changes I named them Job and Jobs. When I run the project and try to retrieve the data it is telling me it cannot find dbo.Jobs1. I do not have anything in my code that would make entity framework create these tables in the first place. Also my AspNet _Migration table does not exist anymore. I deleted it due to changes and the system usually puts a new one back but it doesn't appear to do this either. Not important to me unless someone can tell me that it will break the system if not there or that the problem I am having is related. I have done a search in the project for dbo.Jobs1 and just Jobs1 and nothing comes up. Could someone direct me as to where to correct this and maybe why it created these tables in that fashion in the first place. Thank you.

These are the models of question in my project:

```
public class Job
{
    public Job()
    {
        SubJobs = new List<Jobs>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string TopLvlJob { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ExtDescription { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Drawing { get; set; }
    public bool UpgradeAvailable { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Jobs> SubJobs { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
    public class Jobs
{
    public Jobs()
    {
        Parts = new List<MaterialRequired>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string Drawing { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ExtDescription { get; set; }
    public string TopLvlJob { get; set; }
    public bool IsViewable { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<MaterialRequired> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: > "I am confused as to why it called the tables these names" - there is a default convention in EF to pluralise the table names.

Comment: Have you been modifying the SQL tables yourself?  With EF (code first, which it seems you're using), you need to let EF manage the (schema of the) tables.  That migrations table is an important part of it.  You cannot - unless you know the migrations process very well - make schema changes in the database yourself.  If you've already done that, and it's an option, clear out the database and let it start again (usually with "update database" in the Powershell window, but depends on your configuration)

Comment: You probably also want to think of a slightly more-significantly different name for one of those classes ("Job" and "Jobs"); even if it can work, you'll just cause confusion...

Comment: So I should rename the tables back to Jobs and Jobs1. It does not appear to create these tables any either. I at 1 time deleted all the tables and rebuilt the project, it did not create these tables on that instance. Another option might be to just rename the models to JBJob and JBJobs and then rename the tables also. I have created models and then created tables in this project with no issues. So what you are saying is that if I have a model that does not end in an S it automatically creates it with an S. Why would it do that? it seems silly to me.

Comment: The convention assumes you define your model in the singular (e.g. "Job") and hence names the table - which will be a collection of many Jobs - the plural of that ("Jobs").

Comment: Yes I have been modifying tables in SQL. While coding I find things that are useful and add them to the tables. These tables have a huge amount of data in them. Re-creating them would be a bit of a task. I am unsure why it created them in the first place, there is no code in my entities that states -  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JobConfiguration()); on the other hand I could add modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); to it and get rid of the issue all together, if I decided to rebuild. I am not use to using migration it would be new venture for me.

Comment: Re modifying tables, you should get it back to a state where the schema in the database matches EF's expectation based on your coded model.  EF does some checks to verify that this is that case when it first connects to the database.  Unless you understand EF migrations very well, or you remember exactly what you changed and can undo it, you won't know what that is.  If you can't wipe the data, you could (carefully) point it at a fresh database, get it to create the schema there, then compare; hopefully that would remind you of changes you made.

Comment: BTW EF only cares about _its_ tables; there is nothing stopping you having other tables in the same database.  But for the tables it cares about, the schemas must match EF's expectation (certainly unless you understand this well-enough to deviate from it).  In case I haven't repeated it enough now: _let EF manage that schema_.  Don't modify it yourself.

Comment: Got it. I have just backed up the database and am going to add the modelBuilder to the entities. Also I am going to rename the 2 tables to something less confusing. thanks for all of your help. I guess I should learn how to use migrations.

Comment: While I agree that classes called `Job` and `Jobs` are confusing, you are **not** forced to change your table names in the database. After all, EF is ORM(apper). When the conventional names does not match the database, you could "override" (map) them by either data annotations or fluent API. For instance, you could decorate your `Job` class with `[Table("Job")]` and your `Jobs` class - with `[Table("Jobs")]` respectively and keep the database as is.

Comment: Thanks, I actually forgot about that. However I am of the mindset to do things right the first time before deployment. So I will rename and do some cleaning on other objects as well before I recreate. I have it backed up so I feel pretty good about not loosing anything on the SQL side.